clang 18 stop_token file not found
I have just build clang 18 from sources, but the stop_token header seems to be missing.
According to Compiler Support the it should be there. Any idea if any other argument is needed?
$ llvm-project/build/bin/clang -v
clang version 18.1.4 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git e6c3289804a67ea0bb6a86fadbe454dd93b8d855)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/user/llvm-project/build/bin


$ llvm-project/build/bin/clang++ -fexperimental-library -std=c++26 ex2.cpp -o bin
ex2.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stop_token' file not found
    1 | #include <stop_token>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


Have you also built libc++ from source and installed it? I'm not sure if you changed the default sysroot but that command looks like it'd use your system's standard library.

It doesn't make a difference if I install it.

Well, it won't be used by default. Have you tried manually specifying your libc++'s include path and library path? This is from the docs: -I<libcxx-install-prefix>/include/c++/v1 -L<libcxx-install-prefix>/lib -Wl,-rpath,<libcxx-install-prefix>/lib

When you built clang, did you also build its libc++?  That is required.  Also, as Violet says, it does not look like you have passed the switches to use a custom libc++.  Finally, please add -v to the compile command and edit the question to include that output, which will include the header search paths.
